# The type UrlValidator is deprecated

Tags: java, jsf, validation

i'm writing a custom validator to check the url entered by the user :

```
package tn.talan.testFramework.validators;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

import org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator;





  public class URLCustomValidator implements Validator{

public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,Object value) throws ValidatorException {

    String enteredURL = (String) value;
    String[] schemes = {"http","https"};
    System.out.println(enteredURL);
    FacesMessage message = null ;
    String messageStr = null ;

            UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);


           if (!urlValidator.isValid(enteredURL)) {
               System.out.println("url is invalid valid");
               message = new FacesMessage();
               messageStr = (String)component.getAttributes().get("message");
               if (messageStr == null) {

                    messageStr = "Inavalid URL";

                  }
                  message.setDetail(messageStr);

                  message.setSummary(messageStr);

                  message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

                  throw new ValidatorException(message);
               } 






          }

}
```

I get this warning and i want to solve it :

```
The type UrlValidator is deprecated
```

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UrlValidator from package [org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator](http://org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator) is deprecated, please use UrlValidator from this [Routines](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) package:

Answer (score 1):

According to JavaDoc:

> Use the new UrlValidator in the routines package. This class will be
>   removed in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

The [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html) that you are using is deprecated an will be removed in future releases.

You should replace it by the [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) in the routines package. The routines package can be found in the Apache Commons [Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/) component.